# Expected </VirtualHost> but saw </Directory>

Tags: apache, ubuntu, configuration, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I'm not seeing any syntax errors in this script, but every time I try to start apache, I get: apache2: Syntax error on line 219 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 17 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf: Expected  but saw

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /usr/local/ASUS/www

# Base cofiguration
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

# Reposado
Alias /content /usr/local/ASUS/www/content
usr/local/ASUS/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Margarita
Alias /static /usr/local/ASUS/margarita/static
WSGIDaemonProcess margarita home=/usr/local/ASUS/margarita user=www-data group=www-data threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/ASUS/margarita/margarita.wsgi
usr/local/ASUS/margarita/>
    WSGIProcessGroup margarita
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Logging
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/asus-error.log
LogLevel warn
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/asus-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

line 13:

```
usr/local/ASUS/www/>
```

should be

```
<Directory usr/local/ASUS/www/>
```

The same occurs 4 lines after `#margarita` line, it should be

```
 <Directory usr/local/ASUS/margarita/>
```

Next time you should ask these questions on ServerFault.